# Samsung Galaxy S2 randomly launches applications after factory reset

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I am not sure if this is the correct place for this post. If not kindly refer me.

A Samsung galaxy S2 device randomly launches apps (any kind). these apps immediately relaunch after forcing stop. when media player launches repeatedly the battery drains very fast and the cellular is practically unusable.

Is it possibly a touch screen issue?

I have searched online and found no similar problem.
I have tried factory reset to no avail.

This problem just started with no special update, root or installation as a cause.

Android version 4.1.2
ROM version 3.0.31-816988

- what can be the cause?
- What other steps can I take?

Comment: please mention about android version, ROM, cause of app force close(Eg: after ota update, installing custom ROM etc)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by cause of app close? I have manually forced all apps to close. I have added ROM and android version information.

Comment: I mean that if you have tried to install an update OR tried to root, or install custom ROM's like lineage, cyanogen, resurrection etc.

Comment: I did  not. I can think of no change in installation causing this problem.